# mypy error: Value of type variable "_AnyPath" of "copyfile" cannot be "Union[str, Path]"

Tags: python, mypy

This used to work with an older version (0.6xx?) of mypy:

```
import pathlib
import shutil
from typing import Union

def f(x: Union[str, pathlib.Path]):
    shutil.copyfile("bla", x)
```

but not in mypy 0.710 where it complains:

```
error: Value of type variable "_AnyPath" of "copyfile" cannot be "Union[str, Path]"
```

How should it be fixed?

Comment: I feel like this is a bug/missing feature in mypy -- basically, your error can be boiled down into mypy not handling [this program](https://gist.github.com/Michael0x2a/574fc25e5471463bdb6e18b8b4362144) as expected. I would perhaps try reporting this on the [mypy issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues)?

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the only way:

```
import os
import shutil
from typing import TypeVar

_AnyPath = TypeVar("_AnyPath", str, os.PathLike)

def f(x: _AnyPath):
    shutil.copyfile("bla", x)
```